# Vertical alignment for flexbox CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the vertical alignment of the below code. However, when I tried to add flex-direction: column, and change the margin-left to margin-top, the spacing between "three" and "four" does not work at all. Can anyone enlighten me?

Before i change to vertical flex column direction:

```
<div class="box">
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Three</div>
        <div class="push">Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
      </div>

.box {
  display: flex;
}
.push {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image: Before i change to vertical flex column direction]

After I add flex-direction: column, and change the margin-left to margin-top:

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.push {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code not the screenshot

Comment: Please don't *ever* post images of code, they're absolutely useless (they can't be debugged, they can't converted into code for an IDE or a written answer, they can't be searched and they actively discriminate against disabled users, since assistive technologies are limited as to what they can do with them). Also, how is it in any way convenient for you to screenshot and upload an image, instead of copying & pasting text? Please, see the guidance for "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*".

Comment: you need, align-items: center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the spacing because the height is already max. If you want to use margin-auto you must have more space the the boxes are taking.
In the below image you can see the green box is the wrapper and it has the max height. Once you change your height more the the boxes are taking it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I changed the height and it works as expected!